# Gnuplot: How is possible to correct the range of axis for 3D graph?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to use Gnuplot to have 3D graph for my attached data. Hereby, I used the following command:

```
set ticslevel 0
set dgrid3d 30,30
set style lines 100 lt 5 lw 0.5
set pm3d hidden3d 100
set grid
plot "./1.txt" using 2:3:4 with pm3d
```

But, the problem here is the vertical axis which not show the maximum number available at 4th column of my data (for example we have 4 in column 4th).Could you please put any suggestion regarding the range of axis?
[image]
Here is my data:

1 1.4915 -0.1 1 0.0542767
2 1.4915 1.9 0 0
3 1.4915 3.9 1 0.0542767
4 1.4915 5.9 1 0.0542767
5 1.4915 7.9 0 0
6 1.4915 9.9 1 0.0542767
7 1.4915 11.9 1 0.0542767
8 1.4915 13.9 2 0.108553
9 1.4915 15.9 0 0
10 1.4915 17.9 2 0.108553
11 1.4915 19.9 0 0
12 1.4915 21.9 0 0
13 1.4915 23.9 1 0.0542767
14 1.4915 25.9 1 0.0542767
15 1.4915 27.9 1 0.0542767
16 1.4915 29.9 1 0.0542767
17 1.4915 31.9 1 0.0542767
18 1.4915 33.9 0 0
19 1.4915 35.9 1 0.0542767
20 1.4915 37.9 0 0
21 1.4915 39.9 0 0
22 1.4915 41.9 0 0
23 2.4745 -0.1 0 0
24 2.4745 1.9 0 0
25 2.4745 3.9 1 0.0327152
26 2.4745 5.9 1 0.0327152
27 2.4745 7.9 0 0
28 2.4745 9.9 1 0.0327152
29 2.4745 11.9 0 0
30 2.4745 13.9 0 0
31 2.4745 15.9 2 0.0654303
32 2.4745 17.9 0 0
33 2.4745 19.9 2 0.0654303
34 2.4745 21.9 1 0.0327152
35 2.4745 23.9 3 0.0981455
36 2.4745 25.9 1 0.0327152
37 2.4745 27.9 0 0
38 2.4745 29.9 1 0.0327152
39 2.4745 31.9 1 0.0327152
40 2.4745 33.9 0 0
41 2.4745 35.9 3 0.0981455
42 2.4745 37.9 0 0
43 2.4745 39.9 0 0
44 2.4745 41.9 0 0
45 3.4575 -0.1 0 0
46 3.4575 1.9 2 0.0468279
47 3.4575 3.9 1 0.0234139
48 3.4575 5.9 0 0
49 3.4575 7.9 2 0.0468279
50 3.4575 9.9 1 0.0234139
51 3.4575 11.9 1 0.0234139
52 3.4575 13.9 0 0
53 3.4575 15.9 0 0
54 3.4575 17.9 0 0
55 3.4575 19.9 0 0
56 3.4575 21.9 0 0
57 3.4575 23.9 0 0
58 3.4575 25.9 1 0.0234139
59 3.4575 27.9 0 0
60 3.4575 29.9 1 0.0234139
61 3.4575 31.9 1 0.0234139
62 3.4575 33.9 0 0
63 3.4575 35.9 1 0.0234139
64 3.4575 37.9 0 0
65 3.4575 39.9 0 0
66 3.4575 41.9 2 0.0468279
67 4.4405 -0.1 0 0
68 4.4405 1.9 0 0
69 4.4405 3.9 1 0.0182308
70 4.4405 5.9 1 0.0182308
71 4.4405 7.9 2 0.0364615
72 4.4405 9.9 0 0
73 4.4405 11.9 1 0.0182308
74 4.4405 13.9 1 0.0182308
75 4.4405 15.9 2 0.0364615
76 4.4405 17.9 4 0.072923
77 4.4405 19.9 2 0.0364615
78 4.4405 21.9 0 0
79 4.4405 23.9 1 0.0182308
80 4.4405 25.9 1 0.0182308
81 4.4405 27.9 2 0.0364615
82 4.4405 29.9 2 0.0364615
83 4.4405 31.9 2 0.0364615
84 4.4405 33.9 1 0.0182308
85 4.4405 35.9 0 0
86 4.4405 37.9 1 0.0182308
87 4.4405 39.9 0 0
88 4.4405 41.9 1 0.0182308
89 5.4235 -0.1 0 0
90 5.4235 1.9 1 0.0149265
91 5.4235 3.9 1 0.0149265
92 5.4235 5.9 1 0.0149265
93 5.4235 7.9 0 0
94 5.4235 9.9 3 0.0447794
95 5.4235 11.9 0 0
96 5.4235 13.9 4 0.0597059
97 5.4235 15.9 0 0
98 5.4235 17.9 1 0.0149265
99 5.4235 19.9 1 0.0149265
100 5.4235 21.9 0 0
101 5.4235 23.9 2 0.0298529
102 5.4235 25.9 2 0.0298529
103 5.4235 27.9 0 0
104 5.4235 29.9 1 0.0149265
105 5.4235 31.9 1 0.0149265
106 5.4235 33.9 3 0.0447794
107 5.4235 35.9 1 0.0149265
108 5.4235 37.9 1 0.0149265
109 5.4235 39.9 0 0
110 5.4235 41.9 0 0
111 6.4065 -0.1 0 0
112 6.4065 1.9 2 0.0252724
113 6.4065 3.9 0 0
114 6.4065 5.9 0 0
115 6.4065 7.9 1 0.0126362
116 6.4065 9.9 0 0
117 6.4065 11.9 3 0.0379085
118 6.4065 13.9 1 0.0126362
119 6.4065 15.9 1 0.0126362
120 6.4065 17.9 1 0.0126362
121 6.4065 19.9 0 0
122 6.4065 21.9 1 0.0126362
123 6.4065 23.9 0 0
124 6.4065 25.9 2 0.0252724
125 6.4065 27.9 2 0.0252724
126 6.4065 29.9 1 0.0126362
127 6.4065 31.9 0 0
128 6.4065 33.9 2 0.0252724
129 6.4065 35.9 0 0
130 6.4065 37.9 1 0.0126362
131 6.4065 39.9 1 0.0126362
132 6.4065 41.9 0 0
133 7.3895 -0.1 0 0
134 7.3895 1.9 3 0.0328657
135 7.3895 3.9 1 0.0109552
136 7.3895 5.9 3 0.0328657
137 7.3895 7.9 2 0.0219105
138 7.3895 9.9 4 0.0438209
139 7.3895 11.9 0 0
140 7.3895 13.9 2 0.0219105
141 7.3895 15.9 3 0.0328657
142 7.3895 17.9 0 0
143 7.3895 19.9 6 0.0657314
144 7.3895 21.9 2 0.0219105
145 7.3895 23.9 3 0.0328657
146 7.3895 25.9 4 0.0438209
147 7.3895 27.9 2 0.0219105
148 7.3895 29.9 3 0.0328657
149 7.3895 31.9 1 0.0109552
150 7.3895 33.9 2 0.0219105
151 7.3895 35.9 4 0.0438209
152 7.3895 37.9 3 0.0328657

Comment: Problem solved? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your data is actually a regular grid (22 x 7 data points, actually two lines seem to be missing at the end).
So, maybe depending what exactly you are expecting there might not be a need for using `set dgrid3d` which is meant for non-grid data.
Anyway, it looks to me that you might want to get some smoothing or averaging.
If you just `set dgrid3d` the default is `10 x 10 qnorm 1`. Check `help dgrid3d`:

> The qnorm algorithm calculates a weighted average of the input data at each grid point. Each data point is weighted by the inverse of its distance from the grid point raised to some power. The power is specified as an optional integer parameter that defaults to 1. This algorithm is the default.

So, my understanding is that if your highest data point is by chance not on a regular `dgrid3d` point, your maximum might be a different value (that is what you observe).

Two suggestions:

- since your points are in a regular grid, add empty lines where the column 2 value changes.
  Then you can plot your data without `dgrid3d`

or alternatively:

- use `dgrid3d splines`, where the surface will go through your data points. No necessary to insert empty lines into your data.

Note: if you have a MxN grid you will have (M-1)*(N-1) surface elements defined by 4 points. You can define which color each element should have. Check `help corners2color` and [here](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/pm3d.html), the very last graph. In your case, `max` would be suitable.

**Data:** `SO74912379.dat`

```
1 1.4915 -0.1 1 0.0542767
2 1.4915 1.9 0 0
3 1.4915 3.9 1 0.0542767
4 1.4915 5.9 1 0.0542767
5 1.4915 7.9 0 0
6 1.4915 9.9 1 0.0542767
7 1.4915 11.9 1 0.0542767
8 1.4915 13.9 2 0.108553
9 1.4915 15.9 0 0
10 1.4915 17.9 2 0.108553
11 1.4915 19.9 0 0
12 1.4915 21.9 0 0
13 1.4915 23.9 1 0.0542767
14 1.4915 25.9 1 0.0542767
15 1.4915 27.9 1 0.0542767
16 1.4915 29.9 1 0.0542767
17 1.4915 31.9 1 0.0542767
18 1.4915 33.9 0 0
19 1.4915 35.9 1 0.0542767
20 1.4915 37.9 0 0
21 1.4915 39.9 0 0
22 1.4915 41.9 0 0

23 2.4745 -0.1 0 0
24 2.4745 1.9 0 0
25 2.4745 3.9 1 0.0327152
26 2.4745 5.9 1 0.0327152
27 2.4745 7.9 0 0
28 2.4745 9.9 1 0.0327152
29 2.4745 11.9 0 0
30 2.4745 13.9 0 0
31 2.4745 15.9 2 0.0654303
32 2.4745 17.9 0 0
33 2.4745 19.9 2 0.0654303
34 2.4745 21.9 1 0.0327152
35 2.4745 23.9 3 0.0981455
36 2.4745 25.9 1 0.0327152
37 2.4745 27.9 0 0
38 2.4745 29.9 1 0.0327152
39 2.4745 31.9 1 0.0327152
40 2.4745 33.9 0 0
41 2.4745 35.9 3 0.0981455
42 2.4745 37.9 0 0
43 2.4745 39.9 0 0
44 2.4745 41.9 0 0

45 3.4575 -0.1 0 0
46 3.4575 1.9 2 0.0468279
47 3.4575 3.9 1 0.0234139
48 3.4575 5.9 0 0
49 3.4575 7.9 2 0.0468279
50 3.4575 9.9 1 0.0234139
51 3.4575 11.9 1 0.0234139
52 3.4575 13.9 0 0
53 3.4575 15.9 0 0
54 3.4575 17.9 0 0
55 3.4575 19.9 0 0
56 3.4575 21.9 0 0
57 3.4575 23.9 0 0
58 3.4575 25.9 1 0.0234139
59 3.4575 27.9 0 0
60 3.4575 29.9 1 0.0234139
61 3.4575 31.9 1 0.0234139
62 3.4575 33.9 0 0
63 3.4575 35.9 1 0.0234139
64 3.4575 37.9 0 0
65 3.4575 39.9 0 0
66 3.4575 41.9 2 0.0468279

67 4.4405 -0.1 0 0
68 4.4405 1.9 0 0
69 4.4405 3.9 1 0.0182308
70 4.4405 5.9 1 0.0182308
71 4.4405 7.9 2 0.0364615
72 4.4405 9.9 0 0
73 4.4405 11.9 1 0.0182308
74 4.4405 13.9 1 0.0182308
75 4.4405 15.9 2 0.0364615
76 4.4405 17.9 4 0.072923
77 4.4405 19.9 2 0.0364615
78 4.4405 21.9 0 0
79 4.4405 23.9 1 0.0182308
80 4.4405 25.9 1 0.0182308
81 4.4405 27.9 2 0.0364615
82 4.4405 29.9 2 0.0364615
83 4.4405 31.9 2 0.0364615
84 4.4405 33.9 1 0.0182308
85 4.4405 35.9 0 0
86 4.4405 37.9 1 0.0182308
87 4.4405 39.9 0 0
88 4.4405 41.9 1 0.0182308

89 5.4235 -0.1 0 0
90 5.4235 1.9 1 0.0149265
91 5.4235 3.9 1 0.0149265
92 5.4235 5.9 1 0.0149265
93 5.4235 7.9 0 0
94 5.4235 9.9 3 0.0447794
95 5.4235 11.9 0 0
96 5.4235 13.9 4 0.0597059
97 5.4235 15.9 0 0
98 5.4235 17.9 1 0.0149265
99 5.4235 19.9 1 0.0149265
100 5.4235 21.9 0 0
101 5.4235 23.9 2 0.0298529
102 5.4235 25.9 2 0.0298529
103 5.4235 27.9 0 0
104 5.4235 29.9 1 0.0149265
105 5.4235 31.9 1 0.0149265
106 5.4235 33.9 3 0.0447794
107 5.4235 35.9 1 0.0149265
108 5.4235 37.9 1 0.0149265
109 5.4235 39.9 0 0
110 5.4235 41.9 0 0

111 6.4065 -0.1 0 0
112 6.4065 1.9 2 0.0252724
113 6.4065 3.9 0 0
114 6.4065 5.9 0 0
115 6.4065 7.9 1 0.0126362
116 6.4065 9.9 0 0
117 6.4065 11.9 3 0.0379085
118 6.4065 13.9 1 0.0126362
119 6.4065 15.9 1 0.0126362
120 6.4065 17.9 1 0.0126362
121 6.4065 19.9 0 0
122 6.4065 21.9 1 0.0126362
123 6.4065 23.9 0 0
124 6.4065 25.9 2 0.0252724
125 6.4065 27.9 2 0.0252724
126 6.4065 29.9 1 0.0126362
127 6.4065 31.9 0 0
128 6.4065 33.9 2 0.0252724
129 6.4065 35.9 0 0
130 6.4065 37.9 1 0.0126362
131 6.4065 39.9 1 0.0126362
132 6.4065 41.9 0 0

133 7.3895 -0.1 0 0
134 7.3895 1.9 3 0.0328657
135 7.3895 3.9 1 0.0109552
136 7.3895 5.9 3 0.0328657
137 7.3895 7.9 2 0.0219105
138 7.3895 9.9 4 0.0438209
139 7.3895 11.9 0 0
140 7.3895 13.9 2 0.0219105
141 7.3895 15.9 3 0.0328657
142 7.3895 17.9 0 0
143 7.3895 19.9 6 0.0657314
144 7.3895 21.9 2 0.0219105
145 7.3895 23.9 3 0.0328657
146 7.3895 25.9 4 0.0438209
147 7.3895 27.9 2 0.0219105
148 7.3895 29.9 3 0.0328657
149 7.3895 31.9 1 0.0109552
150 7.3895 33.9 2 0.0219105
151 7.3895 35.9 4 0.0438209
152 7.3895 37.9 3 0.0328657
# 153 7.3895 39.9 ? ?
# 154 7.3895 41.9 ? ?
```

**Script:**

```
### plot with pm3d
reset session

FILE = "SO74912379.dat"

set xrange[1.4915:7.3895]
set yrange[-0.1:41.9]
set cbrange[0:6]

set ticslevel 0
set style lines 100 lt 5 lw 0.5
set pm3d hidden3d 100 border
set pm3d corners2color max
set grid

set multiplot layout 2,1

    splot FILE using 2:3:4 with pm3d ti "insert empty lines and no dgrid3d"

    set dgrid3d 30,30 splines
    splot FILE using 2:3:4 with pm3d ti "dgrid3d 30,30 splines"`

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]